# Running a method in the background of the Python interpreter

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I've made a class in Python 3.x, that acts as a server. One method manages sending and receiving data via UDP/IP using the *socket* module (the data is stored in *self.cmd*, and *self.msr* respectively).  I want to be able to modify the the *self.msr*, *self.cmd* variables from within the python interpreter *online*. For example:

```
>>> from myserver import MyServer
>>> s = MyServer()
>>> s.bakcground_recv_send() # runs in the background, constantly calling s.recv_msr(), s.send_cmd()
>>> process_data(s.msr) # I use the latest received data
>>> s.cmd[0] = 5 # this will be sent automatically
>>> s.msr # I can see what the newest data is
```

So far, *s.bakcground_recv_send()* does not exist. I need to manually call *s.recv_msr()* each time I want to see update the value of *s.msr* (*s.recv_msr* uses a blocking socket), and then call *s.send_cmd()* to send *s.cmd*.

In this particular case, which module makes more sense: *multiprocess* or *threading*?
Any hints how could I best solve this? I have no experience with either processes or threads (just read a lot, but I am still unsure which way to go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, threading makes most sense. In short, multiprocessing is for running processes on different procesors, threading is for doing things in the background.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I might later come with other questions about the implementation.

Comment: Is it **safe** to directly access the class properties shared with the thread? Typing s.cmd[0] = 5 at the console while the thread is receiving/sending data seems to work without problems. Should I be using _queues_ instead?

Comment: Yes, property access is thread safe. http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm

Comment: How can I automatically stop the thread activity when I delete a MyServer instance? If I `>>> del s`, the thread keeps running in the background.

Comment: @jpmz: That's a new question. But you know there is an API for these modules? And it's documented? :-) And deleting the variablename from the local namespace is not the way to stop the thread.

Comment: Sorry! ;) Thanks for your help, it really got me going on threads!